# I want to read div content without nested div's content using jquery and css selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have this div:

```
<div class='contatiner'>
   <div class='inner-div'>this is inner content</div>

   this is outer content
</div>
```

jquery code:

```
    $(".container *:not(.inner-div)").html();
```

expected result: this is outer content

but i am getting:

```
   <div class='inner-div'>this is inner content</div>

   this is outer content
```

I know this solustion please do not answer this:

```
$("#container")
    .clone()    
    .children() 
    .remove()   
    .end()  
    .text();
```

Comment: "*I know this solustion please do not answer this...*" - *why*? Where does it fail for you, how does it not work? Why is your requirement so unique that it requires a different solution? Why should I, or we re-open your question that *appears to be* a duplicate of many, *many* others?

Comment: I am using php dom to read div content  $html = file_get_html($url);
 $html->find('.container *:not(.inner-div)');

Comment: Then why is that not mentioned in your question? Or in the tags to your question? And is your jQuery/JavaScript implemented server, or client, side? Given the way you're applying your jQuery I fail to see why the same answer wouldn't work for you.

Comment: just as sample, if it is implement in jquery and css selectors then will work with php dom, anyway I am sorry for did not mention that in my question.

Comment: "*...if it is implement in jquery and css selectors then will work with php dom*" - if it will work anyway, why do you feel your question should be reopened?

Comment: because this solution did not solve my problem $("#container")
    .clone()    
    .children() 
    .remove()   
    .end()  
    .text();

Comment: Currently, no; I won't reopen. I have, however, asked for a review by other members of the community to see if I'm wrong (if I *am*, then I'll reopen or, if they're able, they might be able to do so).

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
$(".contatiner").clone().children().remove().end().text();
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z5gen3pu/)**

**SOURCE:**

**[Originally posted by Viral Patel](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-get-text-element-without-child-element/)**

Comment: You should add the link from where you have copied this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/8851526/3637090  :)

Comment: @BojanPetkovski: question similart to this has been posted thousand times.

Comment: @Milind: then you should know to close as duplicate, not plagiarise (though that may have been caused by the lack of alternatives, rather than intent).

Comment: for example `http://viralpatel.net/blogs/jquery-get-text-element-without-child-element/` ,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/jquery-using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26385939/iterate-over-every-element-and-get-only-the-content-that-is-directly-in-the-node, and many more

Comment: yes i know this solution, but note my title is: using jquery and css selector :)

Comment: And how do you think of targeting text using css??

Comment: like this something:  $(".container *:not(.inner-div)").html();

Comment: @David Thomas: could you please remove duplicated mark on it?

Comment: @Ayman: see my comment to the question.

Comment: @AymanHussein: text node is not html element. you can not use all selector `*`